# Seeking Starting Point for $f(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(ax^2 + 1\right)}{x + 1}\:dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to solve the following parameterised definite integral.
$$
f(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(ax^2 + 1\right)}{x + 1}\:dx
$$
Where $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$

I have tried a few different methods that haven't resulted in anything useful. I was hoping to ask for a starting point on this question.

Note - if possible, I'm trying to resolve this integral using Real Analysis only.

---

As per a recommendation provided, I will employ Feynman's Trick (coupled with the Dominated Convergence Theorem and Leibniz's Integral Rule) and differentiate. Firstly though, we observe that $f(0) = 0$. We now proceed by differentiating under the curve with respect to $a$:

\begin{align}
f'(a)& = \frac{d}{da}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(ax^2 + 1\right)}{x + 1}\:dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\big[\ln\left(ax^2 + 1\right)\big]}{x + 1}\:dx \\
& = \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{ax^2 + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + x}\:dx = \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\left(ax^2 + 1\right)\left(x + 1\right)}\:dx
\end{align}
We now apply a Partial Fraction Decomposition on the integrand:
\begin{align}
f'(a) &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{a + 1}\left[\frac{x}{ax^2 + 1} - \frac{1}{ax^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{x + 1}\right]\:dx\\
& = \frac{1}{a + 1}\left[\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left(ax^2 + 1\right) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\arctan\left( \sqrt{a}x\right) + \ln\left(x + 1\right) \right]_0^1 \\
&= \frac{1}{a + 1}\left[\frac{\ln\left(a + 1\right)}{2a} - \frac{\arctan\left( \sqrt{a}\right) }{\sqrt{a}} + \ln(2) \right]
\end{align}

From here, we resolve $f(a)$ by integrating with respect to $a$:
\begin{align}
 f(a) &= \int \frac{1}{a + 1}\left[\frac{\ln\left(a + 1\right)}{2a} - \frac{\arctan\left( \sqrt{a}\right) }{\sqrt{a}} + \ln(2) \right]\:da \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\ln(a + 1)}{a\left(a + 1\right)}\:da - \int \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}\left(a + 1\right)} + \ln(2)\int \frac{1}{a + 1}\:da \\
&= \frac{1}{2}A - B + \ln(2)D
\end{align}
We now resolve each individually (note I will omit the constant of integration till the end). Starting with the easiest $D$:
$$
D = \int \frac{1}{a + 1}\:da = \ln(a + 1)
$$
We now resolve $A$ by applying a Partial Fraction Decomposition:
\begin{align}
A &= \int \ln(a + 1) \left[ \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{a + 1} \right]\:da = \int \frac{\ln(a + 1)}{a}\:da - \int \frac{\ln(a + 1)}{a + 1}\:da \\
&= -\operatorname{Li}_2(-a) - \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(a + 1)
\end{align}
We now resolve $B$. Here we make the substitution $a = b^2$, $b > 0$
\begin{align}
B = \int \frac{\arctan(b)}{b\left(b^2 + 1\right)} \cdot 2b \:db = 2\int \frac{\arctan(b)}{b^2 + 1}\:db = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\arctan^2(b) = \arctan^2\left(\sqrt{a}\right)
\end{align}
Thus, we now may form $f(a)$
\begin{align}
f(a) &= \frac{1}{2}A - B + \ln(2)D \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\operatorname{Li}_2(-a) - \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(a + 1) \right] - \arctan^2\left(\sqrt{a}\right) + \ln(2)\ln(a + 1) + C
\end{align}
Where $C$ is the constant of integration. We resolve $C$ using $f(0) = 0$:
\begin{align}
f(0) = 0 = \frac{1}{2}\left[-\operatorname{Li}_2(0) - \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1) \right] - \arctan^2\left(\sqrt{0}\right) + \ln(2)\ln(0 + 1) + C = 0 + C \rightarrow C = 0
\end{align}
And so,
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(ax^2 + 1\right)}{x + 1}\:dx = \frac{1}{2}\left[-\operatorname{Li}_2(-a) - \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(a + 1) \right] - \arctan^2\left(\sqrt{a}\right) + \ln(2)\ln(a + 1)
$$

Comment: What are the methods you have tried?

Comment: My first attempt was to employ the self similar substitution: 

$$x = \frac{1- t}{1 + t}$$ 

As well as using that under the region of integration we can use 

$$ \frac{1}{1 + x} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n $$

For both (in my attempts) it only resulted in very messy algebra.

Comment: Differentiate the expression instead

Comment: @NinadMunshi - OK great, will try that and add to the question definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feynman's trick seems to be a way
$$f(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\log\left(ax^2 + 1\right)}{x + 1}\,dx$$
$$f'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(x+1) \left(a x^2+1\right)}\,dx=\frac 1 {a+1} \int_0^1\left(\frac{x-1}{a x^2+1}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\,dx$$Assuming $-1\leq \Im\left(\sqrt{a}\right)\leq 1\lor \Re\left(\sqrt{a}\right)>0$
$$f'(a)=\frac{\log (2)}{a+1}+\frac{\log (a+1)}{2 a(a+1)}-\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}{\sqrt{a} (a+1)}$$
$$\int f'(a)\,da=\log (2) \log (a+1)-\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2(-a)-\frac{1}{4} \log ^2(a+1)-\arctan ^{2}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)$$

Comment: Yes - thank you! I was typing out my solution as per this method before I saw the notification of your answer. I have marked it now. Thanks :-)